# What meaning of &= in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, puppeteer

I see the below code inside [GoogleChrome/puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer):

```
    this._modifiers &= ~this._modifierBit(description.key);
```

you can find in this file: [code](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/f5d388af7dda492f3932f8c21e9f132e306565a3/lib/Input.js#L135).

And my question is why use `&=`, and how it works?

Comment: All you need to know is in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators Hard to hammer close as dupe though because you asked for multiple operators, but for `&` this [Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47802087/what-mathematical-function-does-bitwise-and-operator-do-js/47802203), for `~` [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4295578/explanation-of-bitwise-not-operator)

Answer (score 1):

`this._modifiers &= ~this._modifierBit(description.key);` is a short hand of

```
this._modifiers = this._modifiers & ~this._modifierBit(description.key);
```

It depends on the coding style you opt to chose as both of them have same complexity based on computation. That is just a shorthand feature supported by the programming language. Some more examples are:

```
a += 10 equivalent to a = a+10
a *= 10 equivalent to a = a*10
```

Comment: and what is the `~this` means?

Comment: ~this is the bitwise negation (inversion) of this. This is just a common pattern to reset a value, depending on some specific bits (bit mask).