# Generate all possible combinations of variable-length comma-space-separated strings in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, algorithm, function

Input:

```
["A", "B", "C"]
```

Expected output:

```
["A", "B", "C", "A, B", "A, C", "B, C", "A, B, C"]
```

This is a simple example case, but the function should work for strings and arrays of all lengths. Strings may have certain letters repeated, e.g. "AABB", which is distinct from "A" and "B". Order by number of elements first then alphanumerical sort is desired but not required for this solution.

Comment: you should provide what you've tried.

Comment: yr lookin for a brute force

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I ended up using as a basis for my implementation:

https://www.w3resource.com/javascript-exercises/javascript-function-exercise-21.php

Answer (score 1):

You can use a permutation function, and then `join` certain strings after `split`ing them:

```js
const arr = ["A", "B", "C"];

function getCombinations(chars) {
  var result = [];
  var f = function(prefix, chars) {
    for (var i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
      result.push(prefix + chars[i]);
      f(prefix + chars[i], chars.slice(i + 1));
    }
  }
  f('', chars);
  return result;
}

const permutations = getCombinations(arr).map(e => e.length > 1 ? e.split("").join(", ") : e);

console.log(permutations);
```

Permutations function from [this answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/7042).

Comment: Clarified my question a bit, as this appears to be unable to distinguish between strings greater than single letter length.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually something I have been working on in scheme lately, what you appear to be looking for is a procedure that generates a [power set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set#Algorithms) from a set input.  There just happens to be a recursive algorithm that already exists to solve this problem, but it is based on math that I don't need to go into here.

Here is a simple JavaScript implementation from [another post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42773836/how-to-find-all-subsets-of-a-set-in-javascript) that I modified for your problem:

```js
const myList = ["A", "B", "C"];
const powerSet = 
      theArray => theArray.reduce(
        (subsets, value) => subsets.concat(
         subsets.map(set => [value,...set])
        ),
        [[]]
      );

console.log(powerSet(myList));
```