# Finding all combinations of an array that include all values in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, combinations

Lets say i have an array with 3 numbers:

```
[1,2,3]
```

I want to find all combinations of this 3 numbers where all the numbers are included.

Output should look like this:

```
[1,2,3], [1,3,2], [3,1,2], [3,2,1], [2,3,1], [2,1,3]
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42773836/how-to-find-all-subsets-of-a-set-in-javascript#:~:text=You%20can%20easily%20generate%20the,%3D%200%3B%20j%20%3C%20array.

Comment: i need only combinations including all 3 numbers and also i need any given combination of them. 3,2,1 ≠ 1,2,3. Also i dont need 1,1,2 or 1,2,2 etc. Every number can only occure once.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9960925/636077

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit brute force, but if you're only going to have to do this for a list of three elements, this is simple enough.

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
a_comb = [[a[0],a[1],a[2]], [a[0], a[2], a[1]], [a[2], a[0], a[1]], [a[2], a[1], a[0]], [a[1],a[0],a[2]], [a[1],a[2],a[0]]]
```