# Subarrays in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, collections, combinations

I'm quite knew to JavaScript (been studying it only for less than a week now) and am having problems computing the sum of the values in the subarrays I generated from a certain array. I was able to do that using this function:

```
function getSubs(arr) {
  var newarr = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    for (var j = arr.length; j > 0; j--){
      newarr.push(arr.slice(i, j));
    }
  }
  return newarr;
}
```

Now if this function was invoked for example for the array `[1,2,3]`, the result is `[[], [], [], [1], [2], [3], [2, 3], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3]]`. I don't understand why there are three null arrays but this is close to what I'm trying to achieve. Additionally, I want to get the sums of the values in each subarray. I know the code above's very crude. Hope someone can help me improve it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: So `[1,2,3]` is you example input. But what is your desired output? It's not clear what you are trying to do here.

Comment: You are not looping through the nested array and the slice code makes no sense...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition for the nested for is incorrect.
Change it from `j > 0` to `j > i`, and it will work fine:

```
function getSubs(arr){
  var newarr = [];
  for (var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
    for (var j=arr.length;j>i;j--){
      newarr.push(arr.slice(i,j));
    }
  }
  return newarr;
}
```

Input:

```
[1,2,3]
```

Output:

```
[[1,2,3],[1,2],[1],[2,3],[2],[3]]
```

---

Just to note: considering `Array.slice(initialOffset, finalOffset)`, it makes sense to just return a not empty array when `finalOffset > initialOffset`.

Comment: the empty set still needs to be included, since it is considered a subset https://www.google.com/search?q=power+set&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8

Comment: @chiliNUT The OP told just to get rid of the empty subarrays.

Comment: @chiliNUT Just to mention, if the OP really wants a power set, that code wouldn't retrieve `[1,3]` also.

Comment: Thanks a lot! :) Now off to experiment how to get the sums... :)

Comment: @falsarella now that you mentioned it, yes, it doesn't really get that. i thought i had all the possible sub-arrays there. would you have any idea how I can improve the code to get that?

Comment: @falsarella you are right, I read the question as "all subsets of an array" which includes the empty array. @dunkelmee, what exactly are you looking for? Is `[[1],[2],[3],[1,2],[1,3],[2,3],[1,2,3],[]]` the expected output? Or just `[[1],[2],[3],[1,2],[1,3],[2,3],[1,2,3]]`

Comment: @chiliNUT I don't want to include the empty array since that will not have a sum

Comment: word. i think a better title for the question would then be "Find all non-empty subsets of an array"

Comment: @dunkelmeee I think it would suit another question, since it would need recursion, but before that, try it yourself and do some research, look, for example at http://stackoverflow.com/a/5752056/1064325! Also, here goes a tip: if you'll try it alone, make sure to test it with larger arrays!