# Finding all possibilities between 4 percentages

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, performance

I'd like to find a way to combine in an array all possiblities between four percentages.

Results wanted :

```
possibilities = [[100,0,0,0],[99,1,0,0],[99,0,1,0],...,[0,0,1,99],[0,0,0,100]]
```

I'm using this function but it's very slow and doesn't seem to generate all possibilities.

```
combinePossibilities : function(a, min, max) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    function toObject(arr) {
        var rv = {};
        for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i){
            rv['fund'+i] = arr[i];
        }
        return rv;
     }
     var fn = function(n, src, got, all) {
       if (n === 0) {
           if (got.length > 0) {
                var total = 0;
                angular.forEach(got, function(value){
                    total += value; //GET TOTAL OF THE COMBINATION
                });
                if(total === 100){
                    all.push(toObject(got));
                }
            }
            return;
         }
         for (var j = 0; j < src.length; j++) {
             fn(n - 1, src.slice(j + 1), got.concat([src[j]]), all);
         }
         return;
     };
     var all = [];
     for (var i = min; i <= max; i++) {
        console.log(a);
        fn(i, a, [], all);
     }
     deferred.resolve(all);
     return deferred.promise;
}
```

I found this function here [Find all possible subset combos in an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5752002/find-all-possible-subset-combos-in-an-array) and modified it to only take in my array results equal to 100%.

Any clue ?

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by all possibilities? Like `[0, 0, 0, 0]` to `[0, 0, 0, 100]` to `[0, 0, 1, 0]` ultimately to `[100, 100, 100, 100]`?

Comment: Define you problem more clearly. What's the input and what's the expected output?

Comment: @MattBurland, I'd like an array of arrays with all possiblities equal to 100. results = [[100,0,0,0],[99,1,0,0],...,[95,2,1,2],...,[25,25,25,25]...,[0,0,0,100]]. Hope I'm clear enough.

Comment: var anArray = { ofArray { "allPossibilities" : 100 } }

There you go, anArray ofArray with allPossibilities equal to 100

Comment: Why so many arrays?  You want all permutations of 4 whole numbers that sum to 100?

Comment: @Ivar Yes except when the addition of the for value of the array > 100

Comment: @ryanyuyu That would do the trick !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This proposal is a functional recursive function, which takes sum and length. It returns an array with arrays of the combined values from the sum to zero.

```
function combine(sum, length, part) {
    var result = [],
        i = sum;

    part = part || [];
    if (length === 1) {
        return [part.concat(sum)];
    }
    if (length === 0) {
        return [part];
    }
    do {
        result = result.concat(combine(sum - i, length - 1, part.concat(i)));
    } while (i--);
    return result;
}
```

> **How it works:**
>
> It starts with the given `sum` and `length` and an empty `result` set, as well as an iterator variable `i` with the value of `sum`.
>
> If `part` is not given, then an empty array is assigned.
>
> Now follows some checks for the (leftover) `length` and their special treatment, if it is
>
> - `1`: This is last iteration and the `sum` is left, only. Then return the partial result `part` concatenated by `sum` in an array.
> - `0`: No more iteration, then return the partial result `part` in an array.
>
> If the `length` is neither `1` nor `0`, then interate over the `sum` to zero.
>
> The call of `combine` takes the reduced `sum`, the decremented `length` and the partial result `part` with the value of `i`.
>
> The result of the call of `combine()` is concatenated to the `result` set.
>
> **Example for `combine(5, 3)`:**
>
> ```
> length: 21
> [
>     [5, 0, 0],
>     [4, 1, 0],
>     [4, 0, 1],
>     [3, 2, 0],
>     [3, 1, 1],
>     [3, 0, 2],
>     [2, 3, 0],
>     [2, 2, 1],
>     [2, 1, 2],
>     [2, 0, 3],
>     [1, 4, 0],
>     [1, 3, 1],
>     [1, 2, 2],
>     [1, 1, 3],
>     [1, 0, 4],
>     [0, 5, 0],
>     [0, 4, 1],
>     [0, 3, 2],
>     [0, 2, 3],
>     [0, 1, 4],
>     [0, 0, 5]
> ]
> ```

**Working code with two examples:**

- `combine(5, 3)`
- `combine(10, 4)`

```js
function combine(sum, length, part) {
    var result = [],
        i = sum;

    part = part || [];
    if (length === 1) {
        return [part.concat(sum)];

    }
    if (length === 0) {
        return [part];
    }
    do {
        result = result.concat(combine(sum - i, length - 1, part.concat(i)));
    } while (i--);
    return result;
}

function print(array) {
    document.write('<pre>length: ' + array.length + '\n' + JSON.stringify(array, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
}

print(combine(5, 3));
print(combine(10, 4));
```

Comment: This is exactly what i needed. Thank you very much @NinaScholz ! 
176850 possibilities, that's quite a lot.