# How to reduce if conditions in angularjs?

Tags: php, html, angularjs

I have 8 icons like this

[image]

each icon have different functionality. Multiple icons can also click, that have call different functions.

this is just an eg but I  have to do something else.I need to know how I can give a proper if condition for this functionality

now I am doing the following way

html code first 2 icons

```
<input value="1" type="checkbox" name="function[]" id="checkbox_vs1" ng-model="selection[1]"  ng-change="onFChange()"/>
```

and in controller

```
$scope.onFChange = function()
{
     if(this.selection[1] == true && this.selection[2] == false && this.selection[3] == false && this.selection[4] == false && this.selection[5] == false && this.selection[6] == false && this.selection[7] == false && this.selection[6] == false)
             {
                 //call function
             }
}
```

Like this I have to check all the combination is there any simple way i can implement this

Here is the plunker 
https://plnkr.co/edit/HNqc2GaQFgoMwhO5S9Ot link

So this will have 40320 if conditions. I need to reduce this

Thank you

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5752002/find-all-possible-subset-combos-in-an-array

Comment: actually I don't want to return 1&2 combination

Comment: i just want to know how to simplify if condition

Comment: If I understand you correctly. You will have alot of **if** statements like this and you are trying to reduce that? **Switch**?  or **while/do** ?

Comment: @dr Jones I have added the plunker you can check the link

Comment: Pass an argument into the function from view so you know which one is which

Comment: As you make these conditions **40320**? They are recorded somewhere in the database? They then generates a script? Or written in javascript file manually?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you mean?

```
$scope.onFChange = function()
{
     if(this.selection[1] && !this.selection[2] && !this.selection[3] && !this.selection[4] && !this.selection[5] && !this.selection[6] && !this.selection[7] && !this.selection[6])
     {
         //call function
     }
}
```

This is using [truthy](http://adripofjavascript.com/blog/drips/truthy-and-falsy-values-in-javascript.html)'s.

**EDIT**

```
$scope.onFChange = function()
{
     var s1 = selection[1];
     var s2 = selection[2];
     var s3 = selection[3];
     var s4 = selection[4];
     var s5 = selection[5];
     var s6 = selection[6];
     var s7 = selection[7];
     var s8 = selection[8];

     // Condition 1
     if(s1 && !s2 && !s3 && !s4 && !s5 && !s6 && !s7 && !s8)
     {
         //call function
     }
}
```

This would make it easier to write out your conditions.

Comment: won't this still make him use 8 if statements? because for every selection = true he probably has an if

Comment: Depending on your combinations, you will have to write the IF statement. You can simplify the code more but if you are checking for multiple conditions I can't see a way around it.

Answer (score 0):

You can make generic functions for this for example   for this

```
     if(this.selection[1] && !this.selection[2] && !this.selection[3] &&  !this.selection[4] && !this.selection[5] && !this.selection[6] &&   !this.selection[7] && !this.selection[6])
     {
     //call function
     }
     //Code for above function 


     function checkCondition(index,this.selection)
     {
        if(!this.selection[index])
         {
            return false;
         }
      for(var i=1;i<this.selection.length;i++)
       {
         if(this.selection[i]&&i!=index)
          {
                return false;

           }

       }
            return true;

     }
```

Note this is a rough idea for helping you in making approach

Comment: but for each condition I have to call different functions

Comment: actually this will shorten your code  in my approach you have to write this condition only one time not for as many time as you are doing in your current approach

Comment: if i have selected multiple how can i implement this

Comment: you ll have to make  3 different function in accordion to meetup and two items checked at time three items checked at time but it will certainly reduce your code for writing conditions

Comment: actually there is not any built in function or property of angular js/javascript by which you can achieve this you ll have to write this code by loops and functions

Answer (score 0):

Create a function that loops through selection to check if any of the other values are true. Example:

Html:

```
<input value="1" type="checkbox" name="function[]" id="checkbox_vs1" ng-model="selection[1]"  ng-change="onFChange(1)"/>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.onFChange = function(checkedBoxNumber)
{
     if(checkSelection(checkedBoxNumber))
     {
         // Do stuff
     }
}

function checkSelection(checkedBoxNumber) {
    for (var i = 0; i < selection.length; i++) {
        // Check values
        // Return false if other values are true
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: multiple check box also i can select. each combination I have to call different functions

Comment: Could you provide a code example in Plunker or something similar?

Comment: I have added the plunker you can check the link

Comment: Great. What are you actually doing when these are checked? I could provide code to streamline your alert example but it might not help you in your actual scenario.

Comment: each combination I have to call different  function

Comment: If you are doing something **completely** different per combination, then although you could simply the if block, you'd still need an if block for each combination. 

If there's something common between them (e.g. box 1 always calls a particular function and box 3 always calls a particular function) then you could simplify it.

Comment: but 1 and 3 both click will call a different function

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107712/discussion-between-carlos13-and-athi).