# Array Processing logic correction

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, arraylist, multidimensional-array

I have an array `[1,2,4,5,1,7,8,9,2,3]`

and i would like it to generate all subset which sum of values are less than 10

current result  `[[1,2,4],[5,1],[7],[8],[9],[2,3]]`

expected result `[[4,5,1],[9,1],[8,2],[3,7],[1,2]]`

that is what i did

```
var a = [1,2,4,5,1,7,8,9,2,3], tempArr = []; tempSum = 0, result = [];
for (var i = 0;i< a.length; i += 1 ) {
  tempSum+=a[i];
  tempArr.push(a[i]);
  if((tempSum+a[i+1])>10) {
     result.push(tempArr);
     tempSum = 0;
     tempArr = [];
  } else if (i == a.length-1 && tempArr.length > 0) { // if array is [1,2,3]
    result.push(tempArr);
  }
}
```

but it gives me `[[1,2,4],[5,1],[7],[8],[9],[2,3]]`  and it has 6 subset, but i expect to get `[[4,5,1],[9,1],[8,2],[3,7],[1,2]]` which has 5 subset.

Comment: your question speaks about *"by the sum of values less than 10 "*, but you mean in the expected result exactly 10 or groups of less than 10. is another rule, for example to keep the item count in a single array low, like [7, 3] instead of [7, 2, 1]?

Comment: You have only two 1s to start with but use three 1s to produce the result. How so.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below logic is in JavaScript :-

```
var limit = 10;
var  arr = [1,2,4,5,1,7,8,9,2,3];
arr.sort();
var ans = new Array ( );
while(arr.length >0){
    var ts = arr[arr.length-1];
    arr.splice(arr.length-1 , 1);   
    var ta= new Array ( );
    ta.push(ts);
    var x = arr.length-1;
    while(x>=0){    
        if(ts + arr[x] <= limit){       
            ts = ts + arr[x];           
            ta.push(arr[x]);        
            arr.splice(x , 1);
        }
        x= x-1;
    }
        ans.push(JSON.stringify(ta));   
}
alert(ans);
```

It is Giving Output as required .

> [9,1],[8,2],[7,3],[5,4,1],[2]

Comment: i added a const a = a[i+1] ? a[i+1] : 0;

Comment: please let us know which language you are using .

Comment: i am using javascipt

Comment: There are two mistake in asked question .please rectify it
1. generate all subset which sum of values are less than 10 but output contain [(9,1), (8,2), (7,3), (4,5,1)] 
2.there are 2 times "1"  in input but output contain "1" 3 times

Answer (score 1):

I have removed duplicates then added maxSum parameter to [combine function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5752056/2128151) to generate all subset which have those conditions and then sorted subsets by sum of the values and sliced them.

You could change parameters to fit it for your problem.

```js
var arr = [1,2,4,5,1,7,8,9,2,3]
MAX_SUM = 10,
MIN_SUBSET_LEN = 2,
RESULT_LEN = 5;

//remove duplicates
var uniqeSet = arr.filter(function(value, index){ 
  return this.indexOf(value) == index 
},arr);

// a function to get all subset which 
// their length are greater than minLength and 
// sum of values are little than maxSum
var combine = function(sourceArr, minLength, maxSum) {
    var fn = function(n, src, got, all, sum) {
        if(sum <= maxSum){
          if (n == 0) {
            if (got.length > 0) {
                all.push({arr:got,sum:sum});
            }
            return;
          }
          for (var j = 0; j < src.length; j++) {
            var tempSum = sum
            fn(n - 1, src.slice(j + 1), got.concat([src[j]]), all, sum + src[j]);
          }
        }
        return;
    }
    
    var all = [];
    for (var i = minLength; i < sourceArr.length; i++) {
        fn(i, sourceArr, [], all, 0);
    }
    return all;
}


var result = combine(uniqeSet, MIN_SUBSET_LEN, MAX_SUM);

var sortedSliced = result.sort(function(a1, a2){
  return a2.sum - a1.sum;
}).slice(0, RESULT_LEN).map(function(m){return m.arr;});

console.log(JSON.stringify(sortedSliced));
```